# Python Service Error 0xC0000003 - SvcRun() method failed

Tags: python, sql, winapi, web-scraping, pyodbc

I am attempting to make a service that takes multiple different values from a conveyor belt machine every 10 seconds, checks if the conveyor is moving and if it is moving it will insert the machines values into the database.

When I run the service in debug mode, it works fine until the CurrentValues.is_moving() returns True, it is at this point where the program attempts to insert the values into a row on the database MStudioDB.dbo.PowderSystem. When the program tries to do this it crashes and I get the error:

Error 0xC0000003 - The instance's SvcRun() method failed

<Error getting traceback - traceback.print_exception() failed

(null): (null)

My code is:

```
import requests
import pyodbc
import os
import time
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import servicemanager
import win32event
import socket
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# WIN32 SERVICE #
class ConvService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "conv"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Conv Status"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):

        def cls():
            os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

        def print_current_values():
            print("\nCurrent System Values:")
            for name, value in CurrentValues.__dict__.items():
                print("{} ({})".format(name, value))

        def print_datalog_values():
            print("\nDatalog Values:")
            for name, value in DatalogValues.__dict__.items():
                print("{} ({})".format(name, value))

        class CurrentConvStatus:
            def __init__(self,
                         spraypumprunning,
                         sprayburn1running,
                         sprayburn2running,
                         spraytemp1act,
                         spraytemp2act,
                         dryburnerrunning,
                         drytempact,
                         powderfanrunning,
                         curingburnerrunning,
                         curingtempact,
                         convspeedact
                         ):

                self.spraypumprunning = spraypumprunning
                self.sprayburn1running = sprayburn1running
                self.sprayburn2running = sprayburn2running
                self.spraytemp1act = spraytemp1act
                self.spraytemp2act = spraytemp2act
                self.dryburnerrunning = dryburnerrunning
                self.drytempact = drytempact
                self.powderfanrunning = powderfanrunning
                self.curingburnerrunning = curingburnerrunning
                self.curingtempact = curingtempact
                self.convspeedact = convspeedact

            def is_moving(self):
                if int(self.convspeedact) > 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

        class DatalogStatus:
            def __init__(self,
                         runtimemins,
                         conveyortimemins,
                         partcount,
                         conveyorcount,
                         dryertimemins,
                         dryerhitimemins,
                         powdertimemins,
                         curetimemins,
                         curehitimemins,
                         convspeedset,
                         ):
                self.runtimemins = runtimemins
                self.conveyortimemins = conveyortimemins
                self.partcount = partcount
                self.conveyorcount = conveyorcount
                self.dryertimemins = dryertimemins
                self.dryerhitimemins = dryerhitimemins
                self.powdertimemins = powdertimemins
                self.curetimemins = curetimemins
                self.curehitimemins = curehitimemins
                self.convspeedset = convspeedset

        while True:
            cls()
            now = datetime.now()

            # CURRENT SYSTEM VALUES #
            page = requests.get('http://xxx/auto/001/')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            title = soup.title.text
            head = soup.head
            body = soup.body

            txt = page.text
            status = page.status_code

            SprayPumpRunning = soup.select('tr')[1].text
            SprayPumpRunningValue = soup.select('font')[5].text.strip()

            SprayBurn1Running = soup.select('tr')[2].text
            SprayBurn1RunningValue = soup.select('font')[8].text.strip()

            SprayBurn2Running = soup.select('tr')[3].text
            SprayBurn2RunningValue = soup.select('font')[11].text.strip()

            SprayTemp1Act = soup.select('tr')[4].text
            SprayTemp1ActValue = soup.select('font')[14].text.strip()

            SprayTemp2Act = soup.select('tr')[5].text
            SprayTemp2ActValue = soup.select('font')[17].text.strip()

            DryBurnerRunning = soup.select('tr')[6].text
            DryBurnerRunningValue = soup.select('font')[20].text.strip()

            DryTempAct = soup.select('tr')[7].text
            DryTempActValue = soup.select('font')[23].text.strip()

            PowderFanRunning = soup.select('tr')[8].text
            PowderFanRunningValue = soup.select('font')[26].text.strip()

            CuringBurnerRunning = soup.select('tr')[9].text
            CuringBurnerRunningValue = soup.select('font')[29].text.strip()

            CuringTempAct = soup.select('tr')[10].text
            CuringTempActValue = soup.select('font')[32].text.strip()

            ConvSpeedAct = soup.select('tr')[11].text
            ConvSpeedActValue = soup.select('font')[35].text.strip()

            # DATALOG VALUES #
            page2 = requests.get('http://xxx/auto/002/')
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
            title2 = soup2.title.text
            head2 = soup2.head
            body2 = soup2.body

            txt2 = page2.text
            status2 = page.status_code

            RunTimeMins = soup2.select('tr')[1].text
            RunTimeMinsValue = soup2.select('font')[5].text.strip()

            ConveyorTimeMins = soup2.select('tr')[2].text
            ConveyorTimeMinsValue = soup2.select('font')[8].text.strip()

            PartCount = soup2.select('tr')[3].text
            PartCountValue = soup2.select('font')[11].text.strip()

            ConveyorCount = soup2.select('tr')[4].text
            ConveyorCountValue = soup2.select('font')[14].text.strip()

            DryerTimeMins = soup2.select('tr')[5].text
            DryerTimeMinsValue = soup2.select('font')[17].text.strip()

            DryerHiTimeMins = soup2.select('tr')[6].text
            DryerHiTimeMinsValue = soup2.select('font')[20].text.strip()

            PowderTimeMins = soup2.select('tr')[7].text
            PowderTimeMinsValue = soup2.select('font')[23].text.strip()

            CureTimeMins = soup2.select('tr')[8].text
            CureTimeMinsValue = soup2.select('font')[26].text.strip()

            CureHiTimeMins = soup2.select('tr')[9].text
            CureHiTimeMinsValue = soup2.select('font')[29].text.strip()

            ConvSpeedSet = soup2.select('tr')[10].text
            ConvSpeedSetValue = soup2.select('font')[32].text.strip()

            # OBJECTS #
            CurrentValues = CurrentConvStatus(SprayPumpRunningValue,
                                              SprayBurn1RunningValue,
                                              SprayBurn2RunningValue,
                                              SprayTemp1ActValue,
                                              SprayTemp2ActValue,
                                              DryBurnerRunningValue,
                                              DryTempActValue,
                                              PowderFanRunningValue,
                                              CuringBurnerRunningValue,
                                              CuringTempActValue,
                                              ConvSpeedActValue
                                              )

            DatalogValues = DatalogStatus(RunTimeMinsValue,
                                          ConveyorTimeMinsValue,
                                          PartCountValue,
                                          ConveyorCountValue,
                                          DryerTimeMinsValue,
                                          DryerHiTimeMinsValue,
                                          PowderTimeMinsValue,
                                          CureTimeMinsValue,
                                          CureHiTimeMinsValue,
                                          ConvSpeedSetValue
                                          )

            # OUTPUT #
            print(print_current_values())
            print("is the conveyor moving: ", CurrentValues.is_moving())
            print(print_datalog_values())

            # DATABASE #
            conn_str = (
                r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                r'SERVER=xxx;'
                r'DATABASE=MStudioDB;'
                r'UID=xxx;'
                r'PWD=xxx;'
            )
            while CurrentValues.is_moving():
                cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
                cursor = cnxn.cursor()
                cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MStudioDB.dbo.PowderSystem')
                cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO MStudioDB.dbo.PowderSystem(Date, Move, SprayPumpRunning, SprayBurn1Running, 
                SprayBurn2Running, SprayTemp1Act, SprayTemp2Act, DryBurnerRunning, DryTempAct, PowderFanRunning, 
                CuringBurnerRunning, CuringTempAct, LiveSpeedConv, SetSpeedConv) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                ?, ?, ?);''', (now,
                               CurrentValues.is_moving(),
                               CurrentValues.spraypumprunning,
                               CurrentValues.sprayburn1running,
                               CurrentValues.sprayburn2running,
                               int(CurrentValues.spraytemp1act),
                               int(CurrentValues.spraytemp2act),
                               CurrentValues.dryburnerrunning,
                               int(CurrentValues.drytempact),
                               CurrentValues.powderfanrunning,
                               CurrentValues.curingburnerrunning,
                               int(CurrentValues.curingtempact),
                               int(CurrentValues.convspeedact),
                               int(DatalogValues.convspeedset)))
                cnxn.commit()

            time.sleep(10)

        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(ConvService)
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Are your service and the database instance on different machines? If so, is your service running under an account that has permission to communicate over the network?

Comment: Yes the Database is on a different machine to the service, the service is being run under an account that can communicate over the network.